# Alternatives to document.createElement to fire pixels (request image) because of inconsistent results

Tags: javascript

I have JS script on my server that will fire a tracking pixel and serve the appropriate file.

The third party loads my script as source, and calls the "getFile( { ... } ) function on click of their site.

In my JS I use this, but I am not getting consistent results with Safari mac, Pc, and IE (various). It seems like its not loading properly.

```
function getFile(options){

    if ( (!options.email) || (!options.ref3) || (!options.ref4)){
        return false;
    }

    downloadApp();
    var url="http://www.example.com/mysrc?image=1";
    for (var f in options) {
        url=url+"&"+f+"="+encodeURIComponent(options[f]);
    };
    var oImg=document.createElement("img");
    oImg.setAttribute('src', url);
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    oImg.setAttribute('height', '1px');
    oImg.setAttribute('width', '1px');
    document.body.appendChild(oImg);

}
```

So it seems document.body.appendChild isnt working as we'd like in IE / Safari.

What would be an alternative be?

--UPDATE: This script will fire, however, the report example.com domain will not be able to write cookies to the browser (for tracking purposes). It seems there is no work around for safari. They just prohibit this behavior.

IE requires P3P headers it seems.

Comment: What unwanted behaviour is happening in Safari and IE instead? The dom manipulation part (from `var oImg = ...` to `...appendChild(oImg);`) seem to work fine when I try them in Safari.

Comment: Its the cross browser scripting. After a day of battle, safari just outright blocks it unless you have it open in an a tab / browser. Google was fined millions for hacking around it.

Comment: @nickynoodles If crosssite is the problem it's not likely you could change it without a chrome-privileged addon. What was Google fined for?

Comment: Current suite in uk - references to FTC fine as well: http://www.googlelawsuit.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no work around for Safari. Safari requires a Window or Tab be open for a 3rd party to set cookies. Even Iframes would not function properly unless the window or tab was open.

They flat out prohibit third party sites setting cookies.

IE on the other hand was easily fixed by sending P3P headers.